# How do "locks" work in programs for protecting critical sections?

Tags: c, locking

I am currently studying locks and I am confused about the following example of using locks to protect critical sections of code.

Here is my question:

If the Deposit function acquires the lock first, does that mean that the Remove function must wait for the Deposit function to release the lock before being able to do anything else? In other words Remove will be stuck at lock->acquire until Deposit function does lock->release?
[image]

Comment: The lock is also released during the waits (eg. while inside `notFull.wait(&lock)` or `notEmpty.wait(&lock)`), allowing the other thread a chance to grab the lock.

Comment: I had no idea that this was the case, I couldn't find any information about this online, is there some sort of keywords I can search up to read more about this occurance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have multiple actors: *lock*, on which to invoke the `lock` operation, and *condition variables* (named `notEmpty` and `notFull`), on which to `wait`.
Because the question is about lock, the response is - *yes*.
The `remove` will either enter the function or wake up from the wait condition and try to acquire the lock.
Anyway, if the `deposit` function is using it (that is, it has a lock on it, it has acquired it) the `remove` function will hang on that lock until it is freed (or, even better, `release`d).
Note also that when you `wait` on a *condition variable*, the lock is automatically released and reacquired once you wake up. Because of that, the function is not holding the lock forever, that's all.

Comment: If Remove must wait for the lock to be released, how will it ever get to "count--" if in the Deposit function we are stuck in the while loop count ==n?

Comment: Because when you `wait` on a *condition variable*, the lock is automatically released and reacquired once you wake up. So, the `deposit` function is not holding the lock, that's all.

Comment: Holy O_O! I did not realize that!

Comment: So basically once we wait on the condition variable in deposit, the remove function will get their chance to acquire the lock.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really stuck on this wondering how the lock process worked.